# Issue when using OVS-DPDK with Intel SR-IOV Virtual Function

Tags: dpdk, openvswitch

I'm using OVS-DPDK with Intel X710 NIC. What I do are:

- (1) Binding UIO driver for NIC port (e.g igb_uio in case physical function and vfio_pci for virtual function)
- (2) Binding this DPDK port to OVS, called `dpdkport`
- (3) Add a `vhostuser` port to OVS
- (4) Add a flow that forwarding PKT from `vhostuser` to `dpdkport`
- (5) Run a DPDK Packet Generator (e.g. pktgen or testpmd) to port `vhostuser`. These packets are forwarded to dpdkport and then be sent to NIC.

Everything is OK with Physical Function NIC Port. But issue appeared when using "Virtual Function - VF".

When using VF, I dumped port information by using `ovs-ofctl dump-port`. It shows that about all packet are error and can not be sent to NIC.

Error log:
`ovs-ofctl dump-ports ovs-br0 dpdk-p0`

`OFPST_PORT reply (xid=0x4): 1 ports port  "dpdk-p0": rx pkts=0, bytes=0, drop=0, errs=0, frame=?, over=?, crc=? tx pkts=0, bytes=0, drop=0, errs=317971312, coll=?`

Do you have any idea about what happened?

P/s: there is a duplicating item in step (3), so I edited it. I also add the report from ovs about error in packet.

Regards

Michael Tang

Comment: @MichealXIV since you have mentioned the issue appears only for VF, can you please share what is MAC-VLAN value you are steering to VF from PF? happy for a live debug (as I suspect it might be ether header)

Comment: Hi @stackinside, I just used `ovs-ofctl add-flow` to add a rule likes: inport=1,idle_timeout,action=output:2. Port 1 is vhostuser and port 2 is dpdk (that is bound to VF port).

Comment: @VipinVarghese, the Physical Function port MAC is default value from vendor. We have two VFs, their MAC are `00:11:22:33:44:10` and `00:11:22:33:44:11`

Comment: what is mac address traffic you are sending to PF ?

Comment: Hi Vipin, the traffic in generated by dpdk pktgen and then bumped into ‘vhosteruser’ port. OVS will forward these packet to dpdk port that is bound to VF NIC port. The destination MAC of packet is VF MAC.

Comment: I believe you misunderstood the question, what is destination mac address and vlan (if any) send to VF?

Comment: @VipinVarghese, it's `00:11:22:33:44:10`

Comment: theoretically all the steps you have done for VF is correct. Even the data traffic is sent with VF-1 traffic. Unless there is Frame Checksum error based on the rules it should get forwarded to vhost Dpdk interface. I can make myself available for a quick 15 min live debug. Please let me know asap.

Comment: Hi @VipinVarghese, my system is in private network, so it's really hard for the live debug. Could you give more detail information about Frame Checksum?

Comment: I made some searches and just found rx-checksum-offload flag. But as I understand, the error is not in RX path, it's in DPDK port TX path.

Comment: it is hard to debug with live, can you please try the following steps 1) stop ovs, 2) run l2fwd for vf interface with application option `-- -p 0x3 -T 1`, 3) check the traffic is received and forwarded 4) if traffic is forwarded then stop l2fwd and run ovs 5) execute `ovs-vsctl show,  ovs-appctl tnl/ports/show,  ovs-appctl tnl/arp/show, ovs-appctl ovs/route/show,  ovs-appctl dpif/show and ovs-appctl dpctl/dump-flows`

Comment: Hi @VipinVarghese, in the step 2,you want to forward a packet from VF to another VF, don't you? (e.g. forward from VF0 to VF1)

Comment: step 2 you have to run dpdk l2fwd with 2 vf ports instead of ovs with 2 vf. this is to check the traffic you are sending is received with DPDK l2fwd or not

Comment: Based on the update, there look like `errs=317971312` this could be because the checksum or packet format is not proper. Requesting you capture, analyze and fix the same.